# How to check that all values are equal in array using recursion?

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, recursion

I am trying to solve this algorithm recursively; I want to check that all values in the array are the same (or equal to each other). If all values are equal, return true, if they are not, return false. My code is not passing any tests.

```
public boolean allEqual(int[] a, int start, int end){
    if (start > end) return false;
    if (a.length==0) return false;
    if (start==end && a[start] == a[end]) return true;
    if (a[start] != a[end]){
        return false;
    }
    return allEqual(a, start++, end);
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example, where the algorithm returns the wrong result?

Comment: Please provide us a test case, a sample input array, and the expected output. (Are we working with multidimensional arrays? Is this javascript or java?

Comment: If you want a test it surely does not pass (even after the fix by Eran), try a huge array.

Comment: There is no excuse (reason) for doing this recursively - it is HORRIBLY inefficient and will cause stack overflow on a large array. Plus, by comparing with the last element in the array you are deliberately reading non-contiguous blocks of memory which itself slows your program down. Please, never use this for "real" code!

Answer (score 8):

change

```
return allEqual(a, start++, end);
```

to

```
return allEqual(a, start+1, end);
```

`start++` passes the original value of `start` to the recursive call (that's what post increment operator returns), so your recursion will never end and you are probably getting a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Another possible solution would be to use `++start` instead of `start++`. For more informations about pre- and postincrements, you may refere to [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

Comment: Perfect. That fixed it. I also had to change line 2 and 3, (start > end) and (a.length==0) conditions, to return true instead. I guess the tests were set up to declare that no values means that all values are the same.... (ambiguous/subjective?)

Comment: @BCronyn It makes sense to say that all values of an empty array are equal to each other :)

Comment: @BCronyn And I think that the `if (start > end) return false;` line can simply be removed, since that condition will never be true (the recursion ends when start == end), unless you pass invalid arguments to the initial call, in which case it would make more sense to throw an IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 2):

It may be the easiest to simply take the first value of the array and go through until a single value is not the same.

```
public void allEqual(int[] arr) {
    if(arr.length==0) return false;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        if(arr[0]!=arr[i]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Edit: Realized this answer is for doing it with recursion and my answer doesn't do that.

Comment: Good answer regardless ...and you're right, it seems counterintuitive to search for the unequal value, when I am asked to find if all values are equal. I will refactor down the road.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using the classic divide and conquer method. Divide the array into halves until there are two elements, and then check if those are equal. Then conquer them and compare the values. Something like this:

```
class Ideone {

    static boolean checkEquals(int a[], int start, int length) {

        if (length==2)
            return a[start]==a[start+1] && a[start]==a[0];
        else
            return checkEquals(a,start+0,length/2) &&
                   checkEquals(a,start+length/2,length/2);     
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int a[]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
        System.out.println(checkEquals(a,0,8));
    }
}
```

Executed [here](https://ideone.com/C6IM7h).

Comment: is integer length/2 plus integer length/2 always equal to length? try some odd lengths